# How to add floating menu to magento front end just like admin

Tags: magento-1.9, css, frontend, jquery, menu

I need to add floating menu to magento front end, just like it is in admin, Some thing like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following link [link](http://magentosource.blogspot.com/2013/10/create-sticky-menu-in-magento.html) more helpful in creating floating menu. Add following to your .phtml file, replace **.nav-container** with required element class

```
<style type="text/css">
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
                       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                       var stickyNavTop = jQuery('.nav-container').offset().top;
               var stickyNav = function(){
                var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
                    jQuery('.nav-container').addClass('sticky');
                } else {
                    jQuery('.nav-container').removeClass('sticky');
                }
            };

            stickyNav();
            jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
                stickyNav();
            });
        });

</script>
```